# The config reports the $count error message

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

When I submit the password and username, the config file of php is just blank. In order to know what the problem is, I echo all error messages. In the $count query, I write an error message which is "the email and password doesn't match."

```
if($count===1)
   {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit; 
   }
else
   {
    echo "the emailand password doesn't match.";
    exit;
   }
```

And when I resubmit the login form, it prints that echo "the username and password doesn't match." I have checked in the table that the password and username is correct.

Here is the full script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$mysqli = new mysqli("com", "ih", "th", "rcser");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

$myemail= $_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword= $_POST['mypassword'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail = ? and mypassword = ?";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $myemail, $mypassword);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* count */
$count = $stmt->num_rows;

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

if($count===1){
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
header("location:index.php");
exit; 
}
else
{
echo "the email and password doesn't match.";
exit;
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I can't see $username set anywhere. Also, shouldn't count be if($count == 1) not ===

Comment: In what way I should set $username? I have edited the question. Well, I will check it if the === is the problem.

Comment: `==` vs. `===` shouldn't be a problem if the types match

Comment: The $username that you are setting doesn't exist. You need to set it with something, maybe the email. What ever you are checking against. Very easy to get around that login script though.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the error is whether in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail=".$_POST['myemail']." AND mypassword=".$_POST['mypassword']."";
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail=".$myemail." AND mypassword=".$mypassword."";
```

try it

Comment: I have not tried the solution you gave, but how about this statement: `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $myemail, $mypassword);` I think it has explained the query?